# Convert UTC TimeSpan to IST TimeSpan in C#

Tags: c#, timezone

I stored various time of day in TimeSpan on Server in UTC zone. Now I want to retrieve that record in IST zone. On my server data is in the HH:mm:ss format and I want get it back in same format of IST zone. I can convert DateTime to TimeSpan by using following code but I am not able to convert from TimeSpan to TimeSpan.

```
 DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

  TimeZoneInfo istZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");

  DateTime istTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, istZone);

  return string.Format("The date and time are {0}.", istTime.TimeOfDay.ToString().Substring(0, 6));
```

Comment: `TimeSpan` measures a span of time (duration), ***not*** a time of day. Where is this `TimeSpan` in the code you presented?

Comment: A Timespan is a delta between two DateTime objects and doesn't have a TimeZone since the measurements is a differential.

Comment: Ohh. First of all sorry for the delay. I need to edit my question. I mean to say lets user registered at any particular time of a day in UTC. I just want to get that time in IST on the basis of HH:mm:ss only. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
DateTime utcdate = DateTime.ParseExact("6/15/2014 12:00:00 AM", "M/dd/yyyy 
                                       h:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var istdate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcdate,
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
```

Comment: How does this relate to the `TimeSpan`s mentioned by the OP?